# Navigation Bar text color automatically change text color

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, nav

I have a navigation bar that works perfectly fine for my webpage, It has a text color of white with a dark background color, here is a part of the css code:

```
a{
    color: white;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-family: "Calibri";
}
```

the problem is when I used/placed a twitter bootstrap (so it can be resizeble for mobile used) the color of the text in the navigation bar automatically changed from white to "bluish" color. Where can I revert the color back to white without removing the twitter bootstrap?

Comment: CSS might be conflicting, try to add !important for the color you want to show, or try using console in browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try `!important`.

```
a {
    color: white !important;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-family: "Calibri";
}
```

i hope it will work..!
you can try for this code in your code

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, styles from twitter bootstrap have replaced yours.

Please, check files in 'css' folder of bootstrap distr.
For example, I have found following classes in `./css/bootstrap.css` file at lines 233-242:

```
a {
  color: #0088cc;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover,
a:focus {
  color: #005580;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: yeah I also thought of that< i tried looking for this code but it is so time consuming, the !important line of code worked for me.. Thank you!